# Maximizing the number of zero coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Suppose that $B$ is a basis of the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb F$ of prime order $p$. We want to choose $p-1$ pairwise distinct vectors $v_1,\ldots, v_{p-1}\in B$ so that their sum $v_1+\dotsb+v_{p-1}$ has as many vanishing coordinates as possible. Just how many are we guaranteed to have for the optimal choice of $v_1,\ldots,v_{p-1}$? (Assuming that $n$ is divisible by $p-1$ may simplify the things.)

Comment: you can have sum equal to zero

Comment: Not if they're drawn from a basis....

Comment: @Exodd: Since $B$ is a basis, no sum of its elements can be $0$ - or am I missing your point?

Comment: @W-t-P, when you say "optimal choice of $v_1,\dots,v_{p-1}$": do you mean that we get to choose the basis $B$ as well as the $v_j$, or that $B$ is arbitrary and fixed and we're trying to choose the best $v_j$ from it? If the latter, then one can probably arrange for all such sums to have no vanishing coordinates at all sometimes.

Comment: I didn't read basis, but only the "pairwise distinct" vectors that is obvious if they are a basis

Comment: @Exodd: obviously, this is not obvious: nothing prevents one from choosing $p-1$ identical vectors from a given set, be it a basis or not.

Comment: @GregMartin: $B$ is given to us, we choose $v_1,\ldots,v_{p-1}$ to maximize the number of vanishing coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more structure: none are guaranteed.

Suppose $n-1 \geq 2$ and $\gcd(p,n-1) = 1$.
Let $b_i$ be the vector with $0$ in the $i^\text{th}$ position and $1$s in the remaining $n-1$ positions.  Take $B = \{b_i \mid i\in[1,n]\}$.  Regardless of your choice of $p-1$ vectors from $B$, $p-1$ vector components have $p-2$ of the congruence class $1$ and one of the congruence class $0$ and remaining $n-(p-1)$ vector components have $p-1$ of the congruence class $1$, so the sum has no vanishing coordinates.  (To help see this: write the vectors with their components in columns.  The statements above are about the populations in each column.)

(Are we sure this $B$ is a basis?  Consider $\sum_i b_i = (n-1)\mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector all of whose components are the congruence class modulo $p$ containing $1$.  By hypothesis, $\gcd(n-1, p) = 1$, so there are $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $x(n-1) + yp = 1$.  Then
$$  x \sum_i b_i = x(n-1)\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}  \text{.}  $$
Then $-b_j + x \sum_i b_i$ is the vector with the $0$ congruence class in every component except for the $j^\text{th}$ component, which is the $1$ congruence class.)

Some hope of a lower bound on the number of vanishing coordinates might flow from the additional constraint $\gcd(p, n-1)>1$.  Alternatively fixing a basis might produce a bound.

Comment: We cannot have $p\ge n$: in this case it is simply impossible to choose $p-1$ pairwise distinct elements from an $n$-element basis.

Comment: @W-t-P : Fine.  The same argument applies if $p$ and $n-1 \geq 2$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, it certainly works. However, for the generations to come, you may want to make some minor technical corrections. First, "all but $p-1$ positions have $p-2$ of the digit $1$ and one of the digit $0$, and the remaining $n-(p-1)$ positions have $p-1$ of the digit $1$". (Hope I am not mistaken myself.) Second, the condition $\gcd(p,n-1)$ can be dropped if you replace zero/one vectors with the "$a/b$ vectors, where $b\ne 0$, $a\ne 2b$, and $a\ne (1-n)b$.

Comment: @W-t-P : $n$ versus $p$ transpositions (and some adjacent language) fixed.